# Phonegap iOS custom context menu

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, cordova

I'm developing a phonegap app for iOS, an would like to insert a new option in the context menu that shows up after selecting text. I had a look to several post which are quite related, and almost all of them led to [this link](http://www.icab.de/blog/2010/07/11/customize-the-contextual-menu-of-uiwebview/). I followed the instructions of that example, but couldn't make it work, due to my lack of experience with Objective-c. Even so, I'm not sure if that one is a valid solution using Cordova/Phonegap, at least without hacking the framework.
Has somebody accomplished this task?